# Книга Жюль Верна или Жюля Верна?

Tags: ономастика, морфология

Есть такая тенденция, когда говорят о некоторых известных людях (особенно с нерусскими именами) склоняют только фамилию, а имя — нет. Например, "стрелы Робин Гуда", "книги Жюль Верна". Это вообще правильно, можно ли так говорить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В отношении неразрывных, воспринимаемых как единое, личных имен допускается и даже рекомендуется склонение только последней части. Чаще всего это имеет место с писателями и литературными персонажами. Поэтому корректно: "Книга Жюль Верна", "Рассказ Конан Дойля", "Приключения Робин Гуда" и т.п.

Но: "Личная жизнь Жюля Габриеля Верна", "Род Артура Конана Дойла" и проч.

Подробнее [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482) (п. 13.3):

> Я встречал учёных, точно только что соскочивших со страниц романа
>   ***Жюль Верна***, и таких, что с восторженным блеском глаз говорят о тлях и кокцидах, и таких, чья мечта ― добыть шкуру красной дикой
>   собаки, водящейся в центральной Африке, и таких, что, подобно Бодлеру,
>   готовы поверить в подлинную божественность маленьких идолов из дерева
>   и слоновой кости

Гумилев, 1913...
(курсив - мой, b-s)

Пример из нацкорпуса, их там много, ограничиваюсь одним, ибо сам вопрос несколько надуман и не заслуживает особого внимания.

Comment: в пункте 13.3 со ссылкой на Розенталя пишется, что строго литературная норма **только** *Жюля Верна*, но в непринуждённой устной речи встречается и *Жюль Верна*, поэтому в стихах и при передаче устной речи **допускается** несклонение имени.

Где вы там нашли "даже рекомендуется" я не знаю.

Comment: Цитирую:

>Несклонение имени в таких сочетаниях **осуждается** современными нормативными пособиями. Так, у Д. Э. Розенталя сказано: «... романы Жюля Верна (не: «Жюль Верна»)...» (Указ. соч. С. 189. §149, п. 2).
Эта рекомендация излишне категорична. (...) в прозаическом тексте, **передающем непринужденную разговорную речь**, нет необходимости заменять Жюль Верна, Майн Рида, Брет Гарта, Конан Дойля и т. п. строго нормативными сочетаниями со склоняемыми формами имен.

Единственная рекомендация, присутствующая в тексте, а именно "проявлять гибкость" касается исключительно редакторов.

Comment: Вам надо повторить? Извольте.
Хотя обычно я этого не делаю.

Прочитайте текст по ссылке. Там обсуждается Розенталь.

Comment: Персонально для г. Марка Иза:

Несклонение имени в таких сочетаниях осуждается современными нормативными пособиями. Так, у Д. Э. Розенталя сказано: «... романы Жюля Верна (не: «Жюль Верна»)...» (Указ. соч. С. 189. §149, п. 2).

Эта рекомендация излишне категорична. К чему приводит прямолинейное следование ей, показывает следующий пример:...

По указанной ссылке.

Comment: Персонально для behemothusа:

Я это уже процитировал выше (см. 2 комментарий). Где там вы нашли **"даже рекомендуется"**? Допускается в отдельно взятых текстах, не более.

Comment: >Я это уже процитировал выше   
   
Так прочитайте.  
  
>Где там вы нашли "даже рекомендуется"? 

Где я говорил, что нашел там. Я просил Вас прочитать. Где вы там нашли "допускается"? Там ссылка на Розенталя и мнение автора относительно использования формы. Я к нему присоединяюсь: 
***излишне категорично***. Русским по белому. 

А рекомендация вытекает из примеров того абсурда, до которого доводит излишне ретивое следования указаниям (якобы) Розенталя.  

Все. Хватит троллить. Вы прекрасно все понимаете - и цепляетесь к словам. Иначе бы спрашивали, а не доказывали непойми что.  
DIXI.

Comment: Где там пример**ы** абсурда? Там один пример ошибки редактора. После этого примера идёт пояснение, что редактору стоит быть внимательней при редактировании стихотворного текста. И заменять такие конструкции в прозаическом - "передающем непринужденную разговорную речь", тоже необязательно. С каких пор "излишне категорично"), стало "рекомендуется употреблять наоборот"? Если же до ссылки вы высказывали только личное мнение, то почему вы говорите о себе во множественном числе?

Да, о том, что такие конструкции употребляются, я и сам знаю. Другое дело, что употреблять их как раз **не рекомендуют**

Answer (score 8):

По правилам русского языка склоняется всё, что можно склонять. Поэтому правильно: *книги Жюля Верна* и *стрелы Робина Гуда*.

Правда в современном русском наметилась тенденция, в сильно связанных сочетаниях (и у  Робина Гуда и Жюля Верна фамилию отдельно от имени мне слышать не доводилось) склонять только последнюю часть, так, будто это одно слово. Так что, сейчас и что-то вроде *Александр Сергеевича* услышать немудрено. Особенно это задело числительные, и фразы вроде "прибавить к двести пяти" можно услышать повсеместно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в тесте у меня был такой вопрос. *Жюля Верна* будет правильно.